# Why does the && operator break when not using brackets in this C# expression?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, syntax-error

A friend of mine was working on a pull request for a C# project, but got stuck on a compiler error, as a build for the change failed. I checked the syntax, but was sure it was correct.

For this *new* line of code:

```cs
if (PreviewLink && Helpers.IsImageFile(path))
```

The compiler complained with the following:

> error CS1525: Invalid expression term '&&'
>   error CS1002: ; expected
>   error CS1513: } expected

Changing this to the following fixed the compilation issue:

```cs
if ((PreviewLink) && (Helpers.IsImageFile(path)))
```

I don't understand what is going on here, and the compiler error from `msbuild` isn't too helpful. Could someone explain why the first expression without brackets is invalid? What am I missing?

---

Now some background information on the code itself. Both expressions on either side of the `&&` operator are `bool`eans, see the following two signatures:

```cs
public bool PreviewLink { get; set; }
// -- snip --
public static bool IsImageFile(string filePath)
```

The actual change that fixed the compilation issue can be found [here](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/pull/3869/commits/0c43a86e6e0211197e9fc418550ac11e4d9b390b).

These are the AppVeyor builds for the [failed](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ShareX/sharex/builds/21496385/job/0769ns42mu2my237#L114) and then [succesful](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ShareX/sharex/builds/21497298/job/qqsps9085r5ugjcg) commits, for the change linked above. Local builds gave the same results.

Comment: Which version of .NET is this ?

Comment: @Fabjan I believe it's 4.6.2, based on `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>` in a [`csproj`](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/blob/master/ShareX/ShareX.csproj#L13) file. The build on AppVeyor seems to be using the `Visual Studio 2017` image. Not too familiar with C# however.

Comment: Nothing you've shown us can explain this...

Comment: @MatthewWatson The noted (failing) expression is in [this](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/blob/eb0c4a1c131cd79e39126df2054bf7ba7d01d783/ShareX.UploadersLib/FileUploaders/OwnCloud.cs#L184) file. Is there something else I should add?

Comment: Indeed, both code samples work fine. I assume you are missing a `;` or a `{`, or a `}` somewhere and focusing on a different problem. Consider checking the other error messages first.

Comment: @bradbury9 According to the Git commits the if-statement is the only line that changed.

Comment: The [if statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) requires `if (condition and/or conditions)`. So it should be `if (PreviewLink && Helpers.IsImageFile(path))`. I think you started with non-working code.

Comment: @bradbury9 Yes. The commit before the ones I've showed was missing brackets. I'm talking about a breaking build with an if-statement that **has** brackets though.

Comment: In C#, `(PreviewLink && Helpers.IsImageFile(path))` and `((PreviewLink) && (Helpers.IsImageFile(path)))` are precisely equivalent, so your question builds on a false premise.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That is exactly why I don't understand what is going on here. Will attempt to build both variants locally again soon, and report on the results. Don't have a Windows machine available at the moment.

Comment: As long as your question builds on a false premise, and as long as you do not give us enough information for us to reproduce the behavior you ask for, it is impossible to answer your question. Most certainly there is a very basic syntactical error when you get those three compilation errors together. As said in the current answer by Matthew Watson, if you try to start a ___statement___ with the token `&&`, you get the error _CS1525 Invalid expression term '&&'_.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your previous check-in: https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/pull/3869/commits/f779c9d74d40f2bb8f7cf3f82a6686d6d9f76fee

It has the following line:

```
if (PreviewLink) && Helpers.IsImageFile(path)
```

That would give you the compilation error you're seeing, so I think that was the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's clearly incorrect. Changing that to `if (PreviewLink && Helpers.IsImageFile(path))` still fails to build, as you can see in [this](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/pull/3869#commits-pushed-eb0c4a1) pull request.

Comment: @TimVisée The only sane explanation is that you weren't building what you thought you were building. It's way too suspicious that you did have some code that would give that error. If you go and remove the unnecessary parenthesis *now*, does it fail to build, or is it OK now?

Comment: I agree. The previous commit (with the statement you've showed) [produced](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ShareX/sharex/builds/21496385/job/0769ns42mu2my237) the same error. For the following commit with brackets that should fix the issue the [build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ShareX/sharex/builds/21496385/job/0769ns42mu2my237) clearly shows the correct commit is checked out based on the commit hash though. Maybe it's an issue with AppVeyor.

I will attempt to build locally with this change as you suggested soon.

Thanks for your answer.